# What's stopping this HTML table from being completely responsive?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've created a table for a schedule and while it resizes within the browser, when I try to visit via a mobile, it doesn't manage to fully resize.
It looks like this on a phone when I scroll horizontally:

[image]

On my phone it cuts off half of Thursday. 
I've tried everything that I can think of. 
I'm not the most experienced coder and so my code may be a little untidy. 
Can anyone spot why this isn't working? Or is there something I can do to tweak it a little?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```css
body {
  font-family: proxima nova;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  outline: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}

td {
  padding: 1% 2%;
}

th {
  background: #44A499;
  color: white;
  padding: 1% 2%;
}

td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #44A499;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" align="center">
  <div id="head_nav">
    <tr>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Thrusday</th>
    </tr>
  </div>

  <tr>
    <th>16:15 - 17:45 </th>

    <td>
      <!--<div class="content"><span class="hidden"></span>-->Gentle Yoga at the Dragon Theater, Barmouth. </td>
    <td>Gentle Yoga at Calon Lan Yoga Studio, Penrhyndeudraeth.</td>
    <td title="No Class" class="Holiday"></td>


    </div>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>18:00 - 19:45</td>

      <td>Dynamic Yoga at the Dragon Theater, Barmouth.</td>
      <td>Dynamic Yoga at Calon Lan Yoga Studio, Penrhyndeudraeth.</td>
      <td>Ashtanga Flow Yoga at Calon Lan Yoga Studio, Penrhyndeudraeth.</td>


      </div>
  </tr>


  </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It would be more helpful to see a screenshot of the view that *doesn't* work, but best guess is that some of the words are so long that there just isn't room to fit everything on the same line. You'll need to add some hyphens (`&shy;`) or make the font smaller.

Comment: Your have wrong markup, `div`s can't be inside `table` / `tr`, fix that, and the table will become responsive.

Comment: @JJJ Thanks I've added a photo of what it looks like on a phone.

Comment: @Felixmosh I'll give that a go now, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few errors in the code. I eliminated the divs in the table, plus there were a few errors (a `<th>` tag closed with a `</td>` tag and some closing tr tags repeated).
It all worked to me.
I suggest, in order to make the table more readable, to follow w3schools' suggestion to add a container element - in the example is a `<div>` - with a `overflow-x:auto`, in order to display a horizontal scrollbar if the screen is too small to display the full content.

Here's w3schools link to the page "How TO - Responsive Tables": https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_table_responsive.asp

Here's the code without `<div>` and with the `<th>` tag corrected, tested on Safari on an iPhone 5s:

```
<head>
<title>Yoga Classes</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: proxima nova;
    }
    th,td {
        text-align: center;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        outline: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    }
    td {
        padding: 1% 2%;
    }
    th {
        background: #44A499;
        color: white;
        padding: 1% 2%;
    }
    td:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #44A499;
        color: white;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" align="center" >
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Thrusday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>16:15 - 17:45 </th>
        <td><!--<div class="content"><span class="hidden"></span>-->Gentle Yoga at the Dragon Theater, Barmouth. </td>
        <td>Gentle Yoga at Calon Lan Yoga Studio, Penrhyndeudraeth.</td>
        <td title="No Class" class="Holiday"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>18:00 - 19:45</th>
        <td>Dynamic Yoga at the Dragon Theater, Barmouth.</td>
        <td>Dynamic Yoga at Calon Lan Yoga Studio, Penrhyndeudraeth.</td>
        <td>Ashtanga Flow Yoga at Calon Lan Yoga Studio, Penrhyndeudraeth.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Excellent, the W3 Schools suggestion worked! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the markup for you, and limited the `body` to be `300px` for demonstration.

```css
body {
  font-family: proxima nova;
  width: 300px;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  outline: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}

td {
  padding: 1% 2%;
}

th {
  background: #44A499;
  color: white;
  padding: 1% 2%;
}

td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #44A499;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Thrusday</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>16:15 - 17:45 </th>

      <td>
        <!--<div class="content"><span class="hidden"></span>-->Gentle Yoga at the Dragon Theater, Barmouth. </td>
      <td>Gentle Yoga at Calon Lan Yoga Studio, Penrhyndeudraeth.</td>
      <td title="No Class" class="Holiday"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>18:00 - 19:45</th>

      <td>Dynamic Yoga at the Dragon Theater, Barmouth.</td>
      <td>Dynamic Yoga at Calon Lan Yoga Studio, Penrhyndeudraeth.</td>
      <td>Ashtanga Flow Yoga at Calon Lan Yoga Studio, Penrhyndeudraeth.</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fixes Felix. However, I'm still having the same problem. I'm not sure why, as it's working in the snippet. Any more suggestions?